# How to initialize a BigInteger in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, biginteger

Can someone show me how to use the System.Numerics.BigInteger datatype?
I tried using this as a reference -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28VS.100%29.aspx

But System.Numerics namespace isn't there on my computer. I have installed VS2010 Ultimate RC and i have .NET Framework 4.0.
Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: Did you add a reference to the System.Numerics DLL before trying to add the using statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be there, did you remember to add a reference?

Right click your project, click Add Reference, then in the leftmost tab, select System.Numerics

Then you can add it and use it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the reference `System.Numerics` yourself as mentioned in other answers, the `System.Numerics.dll` should be there if you have `.NET 4` installed.

Then, if your value is really a big one and you try:

```
var myBigInteger = new BigInteger(50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
```

You will get a compilation error:

> Bad compile constant value

The simplest approach is to use a text literal:

```
var myBigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
```

Answer (score 2):

<del>What version of .NET 4 is your project targeting?  Make sure it is targeting the entire framework not the client profile.</del>   *I have just confirmed that System.Numerics.dll is part of .NET 4 Client Profile so this shouldn't be the problem.*

Once you have done this make sure that you have referenced `System.Numerics.dll` in your project as well.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `System.Numerics.dll` in references of your project?

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure you [include a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx) to System.Numerics,** otherwise you won't see the namespace. The MSDN documentation is a good source to see which assemblies you have to reference to get which namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

If in Visual Studio 2010, you need to manually add the assembly reference to your project. 
You can do that by Add Reference > .NET and scrolling down until you find System.Numerics (which is System.Numerics.dll) version 4.0.0.0 and select it.

Once you do that, then you need to add a using statement to your code:

```
using System.Numerics;
```

Then to initialize a BigInteger there are several ways:

You can do the following:

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger();
x = BigInteger.Zero; // initializes x to 0
x = BigInteger.One; // initializes x to 1
```

or you can use the constructor with an integer literal

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger();
x = BigInteger(0); // initializes x to 0
x = BigInteger(1); // initializes x to 1
```

or easier

```
BigInteger x;
x = 0; // initializes x to 0
x = 1; // initializes x to 1
```

This last method works fine in C# and VB.NET, however, there are other languages that do not support initializing BigInteger with literals such as: JScript.NET, Phalanger.

Answer (score -1):

Prerequisite : .NET Framework 4

Steps:

1. Add Reference `System.Numerics.dll`
2. Add `Imports System.Numerics` in your class